# Total Quantity for each product query

Tags: sql

I have a table `PRODUCT` with following attributes:

```
PRODUCTCODE(PK)
PRODDESCRIPTION
PRICE
STOCKLEVEL
```

Another table is `PRODLINE` with following attributes:

```
ORDERNUMBER(FK)
PRODCODE(FK)
QUANTITY
```

Now For each product I want to list out the `Product_code`, `stock_level` and the total quantity ordered. How can this be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.PRODUCTCODE, A.STOCKLEVEL, SUM(A.QUANTITY)
FROM PRODUCT A 
INNER JOIN PRODLINE B ON A.PRODUCTCODE=B.PRODCODE
GROUP BY A.PRODUCTCODE
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY A.PRODUCTCODE, A.STOCKLEVEL and not ony GROUP BY A.PRODUCTCODE

Comment: Yes I think you are correct... too tired.  Can you confirm it works and I'll update my answer.